# c programming reading multiple files technique

Tags: c

I am curious what is the best way to open multiple files. I know you use a combination of `FILE *inputfp1;` and `inputfp1 = fopen(argv[1], "r");` then check for errors. I would like to know the best way to do this.

Is it best to open and close one file at a time like this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    char line[80] = {0};
    FILE *inputfp1;
    //input = fopen("myfile.txt", "r");
    inputfp1 = fopen(argv[1], "r");                         //Open file for read.

    if (inputfp1 == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error opening file %s!",argv[1]);    //Program prints error message and closes if file is not found            
        exit(0);
    }

    if( argc == 7 )
    {
        /*printf("The first argument supplied is %s\n", argv[1]);
        printf("The second argument supplied is %s\n", argv[2]);
        printf("The third argument supplied is %s\n", argv[3]);
        printf("The first argument supplied is %s\n", argv[4]);
        printf("The second argument supplied is %s\n", argv[5]);
        printf("The third argument supplied is %s\n", argv[6]);
        printf("The third argument supplied is %s\n", argv[7]);*/
    }
    else if( argc > 7 )
    {
        printf("Too many arguments supplied.\n");
        exit( 1 );
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Not enough arguments supplied. \n");
        exit( 1 );
    }

    //Unique behavior on file1
    while(fgets(line, 80, inputfp1) != NULL)
    {
        //do work on file1
    }
    fclose(inputfp1);

    inputfp1 = fopen(argv[2], "r");                         //Open file for read.

    if (inputfp1 == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error opening file %s!",argv[1]);    //Program prints error message and closes if file is not found            
        exit(0);
    }

    //Unique behavior on file2
    while(fgets(line, 80, inputfp1) != NULL)
    {
        //do work on file2
    }
    fclose(inputfp1);

    return 0;
}
```

Is it better to create all the file pointers and open all the files at once like this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    char line[80] = {0};
    FILE *inputfp1;
    FILE *inputfp2;
    FILE *inputfp3;
    FILE *inputfp4;
    FILE *inputfp5;
    FILE *inputfp6;
    //input = fopen("myfile.txt", "r");
    inputfp1 = fopen(argv[1], "r");                         //Open file for read.
    inputfp2 = fopen(argv[2], "r");                         //Open file for read.
    inputfp3 = fopen(argv[3], "r");                         //Open file for read.
    inputfp4 = fopen(argv[4], "r");                         //Open file for read.
    inputfp5 = fopen(argv[5], "r");                         //Open file for read.
    inputfp6 = fopen(argv[6], "r");                         //Open file for read.

    if (inputfp1 == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error opening file %s!",argv[1]);    //Program prints error message and closes if file is not found            
        exit(0);
    }

    //The rest of error checking. 

    if( argc == 7 )
    {
        /*printf("The first argument supplied is %s\n", argv[1]);
        printf("The second argument supplied is %s\n", argv[2]);
        printf("The third argument supplied is %s\n", argv[3]);
        printf("The first argument supplied is %s\n", argv[4]);
        printf("The second argument supplied is %s\n", argv[5]);
        printf("The third argument supplied is %s\n", argv[6]);
        printf("The third argument supplied is %s\n", argv[7]);*/
    }
    else if( argc > 7 )
    {
        printf("Too many arguments supplied.\n");
        exit( 1 );
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Not enough arguments supplied. \n");
        exit( 1 );
    }

    //Unique behavior on file1
    while(fgets(line, 80, inputfp1) != NULL)
    {
        //do work on file1
    }
    fclose(inputfp1);

    //Unique behavior on file2
    while(fgets(line, 80, inputfp2) != NULL)
    {
        //do work on file2
    }
    fclose(inputfp2);

    //The rest of reading and closing files. 

    return 0;
}
```

Are there any better ways I missed?

Comment: If you only need to use one file at a time, then open them when you need them, and close when you're done. If you need to use all the files concurrently, open them all at once, and close all at the end.

Comment: Use array of File pointers instead of using six of them

Comment: @Barmar I only need one at a time but each file is handled completely different. Thats what I was trying to show when I used multiple `while(fgets(line, 80, inputfp1) != NULL)` loops.

Comment: Open each file when you need it, close it when you're done with it. There's nothing special about opening multiple files.

Answer (score 1):

A good way of doing this would be putting all your file pointers in an array:

> ```
> FILE *inputfp[6];
> ```

```
for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
{
  inputfp[i] = fopen(argv[i+1], "r");                         //Open file for read.

  if (inputfp[i] == NULL)
  {
    printf("Error opening file %s!",argv[i+1]);    //Program prints error message and closes if file is not found            
    exit(0);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it the first way, but use a loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    char line[80] = {0};
    FILE *inputfp1;

    if( argc == 7 )
    {
        /*printf("The first argument supplied is %s\n", argv[1]);
        printf("The second argument supplied is %s\n", argv[2]);
        printf("The third argument supplied is %s\n", argv[3]);
        printf("The first argument supplied is %s\n", argv[4]);
        printf("The second argument supplied is %s\n", argv[5]);
        printf("The third argument supplied is %s\n", argv[6]);
        printf("The third argument supplied is %s\n", argv[7]);*/
    }
    else if( argc > 7 )
    {
        printf("Too many arguments supplied.\n");
        exit( 1 );
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Not enough arguments supplied. \n");
        exit( 1 );
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i)
    {
        inputfp1 = fopen(argv[i], "r");                         //Open file for read.
        if (inputfp1 == NULL)
        {
            printf("Error opening file %s!",argv[i]);    //Program prints error message and closes if file is not found            
            exit(0);
        }

        while(fgets(line, 80, inputfp1) != NULL)
        {
            //do work
        }
        fclose(inputfp1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How would I tell the difference between which file I am using? Each file is handled completely different.

Comment: No difference is apparent from your question or your code, so I have no idea.

Comment: @FredLarson I tried to make more clear. I added more comments to it.

Comment: @FredLarson would this work `while(fgets(line, 80, inputfp1) != NULL && i == 1)` and `while(fgets(line, 80, inputfp1) != NULL && i == 2)`? I always get my while conditions screwed up when using multiple conditions.